# Configuring port on "Default SMTP Virtual Server" in Exchange 2016

Tags: smtp, exchange-2003, exchange-2016

I have an old server running Exchange 2003 on Windows 2003. I'm trying to setup a brand new server running Exchange 2016. There is a massive change between the version and I'm having hard time how to duplicate my Exchange 2003 setup with the new 2016.

On my Exchange 2003 I have a SMTP Connection that forwards all emails to my webhost smtp server.

[SMTP Connector to webhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMnJK.png)

Then I have the Default SMTP Virtual Server configured to use TCP Port 2525 for the outgoing connection.

[Default SMTP Virtual Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSasW.png)

In Exchange 2016 I've been able to add the send connection by going to mail flow> send connectors. How can I configure exchange to use port 2525 when forwarding emails to the webhost?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer you'll have to use exchange shell. https://authsmtp.com/exchange-2016/exchange2016_alternative_port.html